# How do I create a batch file that will allow my python script to take 2 inputs

Tags: python, batch-file, command-line-arguments

My python script requires two inputs from the command line like this:

```
project.py input1.txt input2.txt
```

I'm trying to make a batch file that will just prompt for the name of the inputs and then run my script. Here's what I have so far:

```
@echo off
set /p inputName="Enter File Name: " %=%
set /p scoring="Enter Scoring Matrix Name: " %=%
type %inputName% %scoring% | project2.py 

PAUSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the purpose of the trailing `%=%` on your `set` lines?  Baffling to me ;-)

What you want at the end is simple:

```
project.py %inputName% %scoring%
```

It doesn't make sense to use `type` - that command is to print the contents of a file, and the expansion of `%inputName% %scoring%` is not a file path.

Comment: yes, that line worked perfectly! and I'm not sure exactly what %=% is. I saw it on another site and thought it had to do with the prompting for the name :)